# How to send both attached image files and same image embedded to html email body in a mail using python smtplib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send email with attached image files and embedded image files inside a email body using HTML template, so far I can only attach image files but embedded image files doesn't appears in the mail . It says The link image cannot be displayed file may be removed, deleted or renamed. verify link point to correct image file and location and also files attached are of same size. below is the code which I used

```
import datetime
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import glob, os
import argparse
import smtplib
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from os.path import basename
import os
import shutil
import socket
import ntpath
from jinja2 import Template

def send_mail(send_from: str, subject: str, text: str,send_to: list, files= None):

    send_to= default_address if not send_to else send_to
    main = Template('''
    <html><body>
    {% for image in pictures %}<img src="cid:{{image}}">{% endfor %}
    </body></html>''')  
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    html = main.render(pictures=files)
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part2)
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(send_to)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            msgImage = MIMEImage(fil.read())
            ext = f.split('.')[-1:]
            attachedfile = MIMEApplication(fil.read(), _subtype = ext)
            fil.close()
            msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(f))
            msgImage.add_header('content-Disposition','inline',filename=f)
            msg.attach(msgImage)
            attachedfile.add_header(
                'content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=basename(f) )
        msg.attach(msgImage)
        msg.attach(attachedfile)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp-mail.outlook.com", port= 25)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(usr,pwd)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
send_mail(send_from= frommail,
subject="Daily backup Testing",
text='files added: ',
send_to= tomail,
files= files_list)
```

I get mail as this [image]. Image path files are correct. when I print I get this `files ['check123\\Screenshot (161).png', 'check123\\Screenshot (163).png', 'check123\\Screenshot (164).png']` 
I don't know where I'm doing wrong , If the file path is wrong it should've given error while reading file itself fil.read(). Can anyone point me the mistake in my code? thanks